# how to change a UIbutton in a collection view?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a collection view with a like button on each. I also have a refresh button, although I do not know if it is relevant.

How do I change the image of the button after it is pressed?

I tried adding this, but nothing happens:

```
@IBOutlet weak var likeNot: UIButton!



    @IBAction func likeIt(_ sender: UIButton) {

        func viewDidLoad() {
                   super.viewDidLoad()

        self.likeNot.setImage(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "like"), for: .normal)
        self.likeNot.setImage(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "likeSelected"), for: .selected)
//        likeIt.setImage(UIImage(named: "likeSelected"), for: .highlighted)
        }
    }
```

I also have a refresh button. Will that interferes?

```
@IBAction func refresh_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        loadTopPosts()
    }

    func loadTopPosts() {
        ProgressHUD.show("Loading...", interaction: false)
        self.posts.removeAll()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        Api.Post.observeTopPosts { (post) in
            self.posts.append(post)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            ProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `likeIt(_:)` function is not doing anything because you're only defining another function for some reason inside of it (`viewDidLoad`). Just call `setImage(_:for:)` on the buttons without the inner function:

```
@IBAction func likeIt(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.likeNot.setImage(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "like"), for: .normal)
        self.likeNot.setImage(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "likeSelected"), for: .selected)
//        likeIt.setImage(UIImage(named: "likeSelected"), for: .highlighted)
}
```

Comment: when I do that I get this error when I press on the button.

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: I think the reason is that it is located on a collection view. I only want to press it on a specific collection view instead it tries to select it on ever one of them. Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I am assuming that likeIt is located inside an UICollectionViewCell subclass. Whenever you select the button inside the cell, the @IBAction should be called with no issues. Unfortunately, that error can be pretty much anything and I can't really help you. Maybe recheck if the outlets are correctly connected, the images are being loaded, etc.

Comment: it is located in class PhotoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {} is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. If still no lucky, I believe it's a different issue that we would need more details from your code to know what's going on...